# How to disable auto increment Identifier (id) of the neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm working with two relational and non relational banks. I need the relational IDs to be attributes for nodes in the non relational database, but Neo4j does not allow the generation of these attributes.

Comment: you cannot change neo4j native ids, but you can easily set up your own id system within neo4j by adding for example `id` property on your nodes/relationship that are inline from your relational db

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the internal Neo4j id, that's necessary for Neo4j to run properly.

What you can do is introduce your own id field (`id` is a valid property you could use, as the internal neo4j id does not use the `id` field) and add an index (or unique constraint, if needed).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did as directed.